# SSRS: Default parameters are not taking values in a linked report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

My report requirement is that i have 2 SSRS reports that are linked to each other and call each other report internally.

Both the reports have same set of parameters and same properties for all parameters (like multi select, default to ALL etc). And both the reports works fine when opened individually.

The problem statement,
when I run one report, I enter mandatory parameters(date range) and (optional parameters are default to "ALL") the report gets displayed. Then I want to click on the link that is pointing to 2nd report. since I have already given some set of parameters to the first report, I expect the 2nd report displays the results with out asking me to enter parameters again. But its not happening. The 2nd report is expecting to enter those parameters manually!!

where to change the settings so that the 2nd report when called from the first report displays the results with out asking to enter parameters again??

Thanks in advance,
Balaji

Comment: have you specified the parameters in the action properties of the link?

Comment: yes I specified them in the action properties